# a=list().append("hello") vs a=list(); a.append("hello") in python?

Tags: python, list

I have

```
try:
    a = list().append('hello')
```

but `a` is `NoneType`

```
try:
    b = list()
    b.append('hello')
```

and `b` is a `list` type

I think `list()` returns a list object, and `list().append('hello')` will use the return list to do append, but why is the value of `a` `None`?

Comment: Suggest you edit the question title - it is hard to parse mentally in such bold font

Comment: You almost always want to use `a = []` instead of `a = list()`, by the way. Makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`list()` does indeed return an empty list (`[]`), but the `append` method operates on a list *in-place* - it changes the list itself, and doesn't return a new list. It returns `None` instead.

For example:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append('hello')  # appends 'hello' to the list
>>> lst
['hello']
>>> result = lst.append('world')  # append method returns None
>>> result  # nothing is displayed
>>> print result
None
>>> lst  # the list contains 'world' as well now
['hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Thanks for "it changes the list itself, and doesn't return a new list." this statemetn.I understand

Answer (score 2):

```
a = list().append('hello')
```

The above line, would create a new list, then invoke the `append()` method, and just store the return code of `append()` to the variable `a`. And since the value is `None`, it just means that the `append()` method does not have a return value.

To confirm this, you could try this:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> result = a.append('hello')
>>> print a
['hello']
>>> print result
None
```

Comment: Yes, I have known, I forget the append's return value. 3Q

Answer (score 2):

You already got the answer to your question, but I'd just point out that the best way to do what you're trying to do is neither.  It should be:

```
a = [ 'hello' ]
```